# Deployment of classification model using Flask

Tags: python, html, flask, conv-neural-network

I am trying to deploy trained classification model of radiological images using Flask. but i got "Internal Application Error"[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evbOa.png)
But I'am getting following error when I run host. 
below is index.html, front end from where I can get my input image to classification. so could u just help me of finding the way from getting the input image from my index.html and get a prediction by my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   <head>
      <title>File Upload Box</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <h3><b><u><center>Classification of Radiological images using Convolution Neural Network</center></u></b></h3> 
      <form action="/index" method="POST">

         <input type = "file" name = "fileupload" accept "image/*" />
 
        <center>
         <button type="button">Get Prediction!</button>
         </center>
      </form>
   </body>
 
</html>
```

below is my app.py flask script

```
def generate_prediction(input):
      model=load_model('./models/model.h5')
      #Normalizing the inputs
      IMG_SIZE = 100
      img_array = cv2.imread(input, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
      img_array = img_array/255.0
      new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
      input = new_array.reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)

      #input=(input-mean)/std
      pred= model.predict(input)
      pred = list(pred[0])
      return pred

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET'])
def home():
      return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/get_price', methods=['POST'])
def get_price():
      CATEGORIES = ["Brain", "Hands", "Kidney", "Legs", "Lungs", "Skull", "Teeth"]

      K.clear_session()
      input=request.form.to_dict()
      #input=np.array(list(input.values()))
      prediction=generate_prediction(input)
      return CATEGORIES[prediction.index(max(prediction))]
      #print(max(prediction)*100)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #app.debug = True
    app.run(host='192.168.72.1',port=5000)
```

Comment: Your form routes the POST request to /index. But you have no handler for /index in your app.py. You only have / and /get_price.

Answer (score 0):

Your form should be

```
<form action="/get_price" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type = "file" name = "fileupload" accept "image/*" />

    <center>
         <button type="button">Get Prediction!</button>
    </center>
</form>
```

to get the image inside of your controller do the following

```
@app.route('/get_price', methods=['POST'])
def get_price():
      CATEGORIES = ["Brain", "Hands", "Kidney", "Legs", "Lungs", "Skull", "Teeth"]

      K.clear_session()
      # like this you will only get the File object you uploaded
      input = request.files.get('fileupload', None)
      prediction=generate_prediction(input)
      return CATEGORIES[prediction.index(max(prediction))]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but now I am getting the error  "The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again." why this error occurs? so could just help me out this.

Comment: Can you make sure that you have shut down all the previously run instances of the app?

Comment: or just restart it from your IDE

Comment: no..both ways are not working for me. is there any config or init_app file required in flask app root folder?

Comment: Can you try changing your host to `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)`?

Comment: is "request.files.get('fileupload', None)" this line gives me file path which is store in my input variable.